# Laravel SwiftMailer : Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, swiftmailer

I am using laravel 5.2, And the using Swift Mailer for password resetting.
**I have 2-step verification on my gmail.**.

As the google help says :

---

If you've turned on 2-Step Verification for your account, you might need to enter an App password instead of your regular password.

---

I have the following settings on `mail.php` :

```
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
    'from' => ['address' => 'meaprogrammer@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Shafee'],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
    'username' => env('meaprogrammer@gmail.com'),
    'password' => env('MY_Gmail_API_KEY'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => env('MAIL_PRETEND', false),

];
```

On the `.env` i have :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=meaprogrammer@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=MY_Gmail_API_KEY
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

The following error comes up :

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:

Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. 

Learn more at
530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 w10sm15831823wjk.18 - gsmtp
"
```

Comment: Is `MY_Gmail_API_KEY` an actual API key? I've always just used the google password for the account in the username field (`meaprogrammer@gmail.com`).

Comment: @Hpierce Should i use the meaprogrammer@gmail.com `password` both in `.env` and `mail.php` ?

Comment: I have updated the question please have  a look.

Comment: I'm still not quite clear, are you suggesting `MY_Gmail_API_KEY` is the App password? That's what it should be, but I personally wouldn't call it an API key.

Comment: Okay i am using my gmail password but still the same issue !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to turn on "less secure apps" of your account on [this page](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps). Read [this google answer](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en).

Comment: Still not working... Should i use the app secret key or my gmail password ?

Comment: Use password for this

Comment: Use your password for `MAIL_PASSWORD` instead of API key.

Comment: Same issue ... With `MAIL_PASSWORD`

Comment: You also need to add
$options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE; 
$options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;

code in vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\SteamBuffer.php in establishSocketConnection() function after just defining $options = [];

Answer (score 6):

Use tls instead of ssl and use port 587.

Use key or paasword.

Or Please run php artisan config:cache

Or Try to turn on "less secure apps" of your account on this page.

Comment: Plz use php mail function without smtp to send mail.

Comment: Or use domain email smtp for sending mails via smtp.

Comment: Or plz try to use password instead of key in .env file

Comment: Please run php artisan config:cache

Comment: And use 587 and tls with key or password. And run php artisan config:cache command before sending mail

Answer (score 2):

**Follow this file......**

Change **"Username" => env('your-gmail-account@gmail.com')** to **"Username" => 'your-gmail-account@gmail.com';**

**Same as Password...**

return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill",
|            "ses", "sparkpost", "log"
|
*/

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => ['address' => 'only5test@gmail.com', 'name' => 'shashikant parmar111'],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

**'username' => 'Your-gmail-account@gmail.com',**

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Password
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
| messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
| connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
|
*/

**'password' => '********',**

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => FALSE,
```

];

Answer (score 2):

In laravel, I was also having the same issue but is because of... I was not using "use clause" in the Mail function .

The error got solved after using "use clause".

Answer (score 1):

You can try following steps

1. Turn on "less secure apps" for your account [here](https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/lesssecureapps).
2. Try by setting your mail encryption to `tls` and port to `587` in your `.env` file 
   MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com 
   MAIL_PORT=587 
   MAIL_USERNAME=your-email@gmail.com 
   MAIL_PASSWORD=your-password 
   MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
3. Then run 
   php artisan cache:clear

This worked just fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

Man, enter google settings, security options, security alerts. There you probably have alerts of google blocks ... your code is fine, only google is blocking you, give it permission and ready ....
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpdr0.png)