# Laravel 5.5 Expected response code 250 but got code "530"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I know it is a duplicate issue in StackOverFlow ([Laravel SwiftMailer : Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37469770/laravel-swiftmailer-expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-530-with-messag)) however, I'm done all the remedies discussed there but still no luck. I'm using mailtrap.io using my GMail account. Here is the .env file and mail.php (under config):

### .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=XXXX
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXXX
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

### mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailtrap.io'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525),
'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'niladriXXX@XXX.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Niladri Banerjee'),
    ],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i',
'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
```

After submitting the valid email from forgot password screen, it throws the following error:

> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required "

Please note: I have already ON 'Allow less secure apps' from "Sign-in & security" from my GMail.

Seeking your help.

PS: I'm running the project in localhost.

Comment: Please provide a link in your question to the question you consider a "duplicate" so people don't flag it.

Comment: @Daniel Link updated.

Comment: You say you are using mailtrap in your env (these values are used) and if they are not defined the 'smtp.gmail.org' values are used. the env() function uses the 2nd parameter as default if the first one is not found in your .env file. So in your case you are probably using gmail credentials for mailtrap.

Comment: @Tuim I have updated the code, can you please check if this all correct?

Comment: @Tuim I've checked and confirmed that I'm not using gmail credentials for mailtrap. I've used my gmail id in mailtrap but using the credentials which mailtrap.io provided me.

Comment: Put your gmail credentials in the .env file. And read how the configuration works: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration

Comment: I have changed the .env file with my gmail id and password and leave the MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null, but still I receive the same error. Is this occur because I'm running this project from localhost?

Comment: @Tuim I have also done - php artisan config:clear but no luck still.

Comment: Don't forget to restart the Laravel development server after changing `.env` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I' may suggest you use this as well, it worked for me,

Please Note if you're using Gmail: create a gmail app password, but be sure to your 2 Step verification set up, from sign in and securiity, the following link: https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords to setup app password, 
use that and follow procedure 2 after this return to set up gmail with smtp.

please note: code down below are for mail.php file

(do not forget to use: php artisan config:cache) 
after changes to .env file as well

```
return [

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailtrap.io'),

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525),

'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'lxxxx@xxxx.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'myMail'),
    ],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),//this setting in .env only leave as is here

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),//this setting in .env only leave as is here

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
    ],

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

//procedure 2 for gmail
return [

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'lxxxx@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'myMail'),
    ],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),//this setting in .env only leave as is here

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),//this setting in .env only (use app password you created for gmail and PLEASE leave as is here

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
    ],

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

Hope it helps. 
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

add MAIL_FROM=mailtrap.io username to your .env file
and  php artisan config:cache.

if you see, mail.php needs this for authentication

[image: if you see, mail.php needs this for authentication]