# SOLUTION for: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.71 Authentication required

Tags: laravel

This first code was what solved everything.  **Use this code exactly inside your config/mail.php file**. With your own full Gmail address and Google app password.

[Where I got the solution](https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/unable-to-email-in-laravel/146429)

```
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME','full-gmail-address-here'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD','Google-app-password-generated-when-setting-up-2-factor-auth'),
```

You might have written this 2nd code but here it is ... **Goes inside your `env` file**.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587 (or use 465 for ssl on the sixth line below)
MAIL_USERNAME=Your-full-Gmail-address-here
MAIL_PASSWORD=Your-Google-App-Password-here
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls (or ssl)
MAIL_AUTH=YES (<= I made this up, if you're a pro you can check if it's necessary)
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=Email-address-of-sender
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Name-of-sender
```

Thirdly, don't forget to include this inside the **config/mail.php file**

```
'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
],
```

Please pass it on to whoever may need it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer but AFAICT this looks identical to other questions here on SO already, eg [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50582000/laravel-5-5-expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-530).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel SwiftMailer : Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37469770/laravel-swiftmailer-expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-530-with-messag)

Answer (score 0):

When change in .env you just clear cache & config

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Then test your .env data

```
php artisan tinker
```

```
config('mail')
```

check your data is correct or not.Your process is correct here.

Comment: OP is actually just posting his working solution - there is no real question here, nothing to answer.