# Swift_TransportException Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required "

Tags: laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and looking to enhance my skills in using Laravel framework 5.4. But I don't know what to do when I encounter this error: 1/1) Swift_TransportException Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required Is it .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel SwiftMailer : Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37469770/laravel-swiftmailer-expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-530-with-messag)

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are many duplicates of this question here on SO, please try searching before opening a new question. If the duplicate does not match your question, please edit it and explain what it is different so we can try to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
make sure that you are using the mail credential in .env file. i think you try to send mail without using the mail credentials.so,
create credentials on sendgrid or any mail service for send mail and put these credentials in .env file.

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=your credentials username
MAIL_PASSWORD=your secret key
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this

'username' => env('ivanedu947@gmail.com'),

'password' => env('password'),

to this

'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME','miemail@gmail.com'),

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD','password'),

and on php line comand key

php artisan config:cache

and its must be works